# Hive error when inserting data into a partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm using Hive 0.12.0 and I've created a partitioned table.

Then I try to insert the data into the table: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'path/data' insert into table test partition (idx=1)`

But then I get the following error:

```
ERROR metastore.RetryingHMSHandler (RetryingHMSHandler.java:invoke(134)) - NoSuchObjectException(message:partition values=[1])
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPartitionWithAuth(ObjectStore.java:1427)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.invoke(RetryingRawStore.java:111)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.getPartitionWithAuth(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_partition_with_auth(HiveMetaStore.java:2025)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.get_partition_with_auth(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$get_partition_with_auth.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:6924)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Processor$get_partition_with_auth.getResult(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:6908)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor.process(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:104)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:206)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What's the solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either pre-generate via add partition the partitions or use dynamic partitions.

Pre-generate partitions:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PARTITION (partCol = 'value1') location 'loc1';
```

Using dynamic partitions:

[Dynamic partitions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions)

Comment: i just got different error-Failed with exception checkPaths: filesystem error in check phase

Comment: That is a separate issue. Please consider to upvote/accept this answer to the OP. Then open a new question.

Comment: Thanks. I will look for your new question.